# Puppet Visual Studio 2012 Update only when needed

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, puppet

I have an EXE that applies update 4 to Visual Studios. However I can't seem to get it to only run when the update is not already installed. Here is my relevant code:

```
 35         package { "Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012":
 36                 ensure  => installed,
 37                 source  => '\\remotelocation\vs_ultimate.exe',
 38                 install_options => [ '/quiet','/norestart' ],
 39         } 
 40
 41         package { "Visual Studio 2012 Update 4":
 42                 ensure  => installed,
 43                 source  => '\\remotelocation\VS2012.4.exe',
 44                 install_options => [ '/quiet','/norestart' ],
 45         }
```

How can I have it only run when needed, or at the very least only run IF the visual studios package was changed this run?

Comment: I'm not sure how Puppet handles this on Windows, but generally for `package` resources, Puppet will only take action if the package is **not already on the system**. I.e., Puppet will try and find *Visual Studio 2012 Update 4* among the installed software. Does it appear in the software list by that name? If yes, does Puppet not recognize it? (Try running with `-dv`.)

Comment: It appears in the update list as opposed to the normal software list. I don't think it recognizes it as installed. Im going to go hunt registry keys to see if it has a different name but I don't think it does.

Comment: Consider opening a [feature request](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com) in this case, so that updates can be supported just like regular packages.